# I want convert from MDF file to Dataframe

Tags: python

> I use MDF file like asammdf or mdfreader. but my data files is too
>   big. so, I want read specific data and make a dataframe.
>
> 1. mdf data reader using asammdf  from asammdf import MDF
>      case in mdfreader, there are many errors because my mdf files are same name data and some trouble in resampling (wrong data come-out)
>
> filename = test_t16.dat"      ; My MDF data file
>
> yop = MDF(filename)           ; mdf reader using asammdf
>
> whl_rr = yop.get('WHL_SPD_RR')     ;I pick some datas from mdf
>   files(yop)
>
> whl_rr =
>
> invalidation_bits = {NoneType} None
>
> master_metadata = {tuple} ('TimeChannel', 1)
>
> name = {str} 'WHL_SPD_RR'
>
> raw = {bool} False
>
> samples = {ndarray} [0. ... 0.]
>
> source = {NoneType} None
>
> stream_sync = {bool} False
>
> timestamps = {ndarray} [ 240.4053  ... 2050.81525]
>
> unit = {str} 'km/h'
>   >
>   I want to dataframe like this

---

```
from asammdf import MDF
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = r"C:\Users\wonyo\PycharmProjects\test\test_t16.dat"
yop = MDF(filename)

signallist = [ "WHL_SPD_RR","WHL_SPD_FR", "WHL_SPD_RL","WHL_SPD_FL"]

df=[]
def group_len(yop, start, stop):             
    for i in range(start, stop):           
        if yop.get_group(i).empty != True:
            if i == start:
                max_len = len(yop.get_group(i).TimeChannel)
                min_time = min(yop.get_group(i).TimeChannel)

            else:
                max_len = min(max_len, len(yop.get_group(i).TimeChannel))
                min_time = max(min_time, min(yop.get_group(i).TimeChannel))

    return max_len-1000, max(242, min_time + 2) 

grlen_time = group_len(yop, 68, 140)
max_len = grlen_time[0]
min_time = grlen_time[1]
time = np.linspace(0, (max_len - 1) * 0.01, max_len)

for i in range(0,5):

    signal = yop.get(signallist[i])
    signal.timestamps = signal.timestamps - min_time
    signal = signal.interp(time)
    data_sg = signal.samples
    name_sg = signal.name
    inex_sg = signal.timestamps
    mydata = pd.DataFrame( data =data_sg , index=index_sg, columns=name_sg)
    print(df)

whl_spd_fl = signal()
```

---

I want to make like this  (dataframe)

```
time    whl_spd_rr    whl_spd_rl   whl_spd_fl    whl_spd_fr
0         0              0            0             0
0.01      1              1            1             1
0.02      2              2            2             2
0.03      4              4            4             4
0.04      10             10           10            10
0.05      15             15           15            15
0.06      20             19           19            19
0.07      21             20           20            20
0.08      22             21           21            21
0.09      24             23           21            22
0.10      10             11           11            11
0.11      8              10           10            10
```

Comment: I solve the problem as asammdf. refer to [link] (https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/issues/104#issuecomment-445840030)

Answer (score 3):

Since at least asammdf version 5.10.3 from [API](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):

> The pandas export option was removed. you should use the method to_dataframe instead.

```
from asammdf import MDF

mdf_obj = MDF('file.mf4')
df = mdf_obj.to_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yop = MDF(file_name, memory='minimum')

to_keep = ['Channl1', 'Channel2', ('CR_Bms_Soc_Pc', 102) ] # and so on
df = yop.filter(to_keep).cut(start=240, stop=2050).export('pandas', raster=0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df= mdf.filter(signallist).export(fmt='pandas')
```

Comment: can you add some explanations why this will help?